# Freezing UITableView on scrolling while using rating star (DLStarRating) in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using [DLStarRating](https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating) for showing rating .Its working perfect but when I am using this in tableview cell then freezing problem start while scrolling.I want to show rating stars in UITableview fractionally[image] Ex:- 3.2 ,1.9,2,4.6 etc ratings.

```
UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
if(cell==nil)
{

[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
   UILabel *LabelTitle= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
LabelTitle.text=[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];


UILabel *LabelAddress= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
LabelAddress.text=[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"];

UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:200];
[imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"icon"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];

DLStarRatingControl *customNumberOfStars = [[DLStarRatingControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 140, 140, 30) andStars:5 isFractional:YES];
customNumberOfStars.delegate = self;
customNumberOfStars.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
customNumberOfStars.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
customNumberOfStars.rating = [[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
[cell addSubview:customNumberOfStars];
    return cell;
```

Comment: What problem you are facing? I didnt get

Comment: the problem is it is working, but as the scrollview is being scrolled, the tableview freezes up

Comment: Yes tableview freezes up on scrolling the table .Any solution?

Comment: TableView can only freeze if you are not reusing UITableView cell properly or fetching data for cell takes time. Can you post code for 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method code.

Comment: Some code would help us help you

Comment: @kkumpavat Please check above code , I am using SDIMageView for caching image and using custom cell to display cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

You should follow below steps.

1. First you need to get reusable cell for identifier.
2. If no reusable cell is available, then create and add required components/subviews in it.
3. Change properties and behaviour of cell and its components/subviews based on your logic.

You do not need to create subview every time as you are doing for DLStarRatingControl. This will affect tableview performance and it will freeze.

By following these steps I would change your implementation as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"CellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil][0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

        DLStarRatingControl *customNumberOfStars = [[DLStarRatingControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 140, 140, 30) andStars:5 isFractional:YES];
        customNumberOfStars.tag = 1001;
        customNumberOfStars.delegate = self;
        customNumberOfStars.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        customNumberOfStars.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        [cell addSubview:customNumberOfStars];
    }
    UILabel *LabelTitle= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    LabelTitle.text=[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];


    UILabel *LabelAddress= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    LabelAddress.text=[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"];

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"icon"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];

    DLStarRatingControl *customNumberOfStars = (customNumberOfStars *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    customNumberOfStars.rating = [[ArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];

    return cell;
}
```

Note that have not user `[UITableView registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:]` because you need to add rating control as subview. You were adding it every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method called, Now it will be added only when new cell is created.

I also suspect table view is freezing because you are loading image from some URL. I am not sure about the size of that Image, but if tableView still freezes you need to implement lazy loading for that image.